# What does a comma do in a python assignment

Tags: python

I have basic knowledge in c++ and I got an assignment to read a code it python and rewrite it in c++. I'm not familiar with python so I'm sorry for any newbie Q :).

In the code I see:

```
before,err = TG.quad(fnx, -N/2, -x)
before_n = before/all

inTime, err = TG.quad(fnx, -x,left)
inTime_n= inTime/all
```

in the first line, are 'before' and 'err' 2 vars who are assigned to the value from the left?

when I try to run an example for myself:

```
b,a= 5
print (a,b)
```

I get the error

> "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable",

what am I missing?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Can't find a dupe with keyword `unpacking`. Whats the correct term for it?

Comment: @MYGz - Multiple assignment, generally. However, I can't find a basic enough duplicate either, as this isn't some kind of special case - it's basically asking for a tutorial on the language.

Comment: He has exception and he has no idea how to figure out what is causing it.
Stack overflow is the place to understand what is causing error in program.

Comment: You've answered your own Question here. :) '...in the first line, are 'before' and 'err' 2 vars who are assigned to the value from the left?" In essence, yes, `TG.quad(fnx, -N/2, -x)` is returning two values that are being assigned to the vars `before` and `err`.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html), under [Data Structures > Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> The statement `t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'` is an example of *tuple packing*: the values `12345`, `54321` and `'hello!'` are packed together in a tuple. The reverse operation is also possible:
>
> ```
> >>> x, y, z = t
> ```
>
> This is called, appropriately enough, *sequence unpacking* and works for any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires that there are as many variables on the left side of the equals sign as there are elements in the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is really just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.

Note this portion:

> Sequence unpacking requires that there are as many variables on the left side of the equals sign as there are elements in the sequence.

The statement `before,err = TG.quad(fnx, -N/2, -x)` fulfills this requirement, but `b,a = 5` does not.

Answer (score 2):

You should have two values for each variables.

```
b,a= 5,5
print (a,b)
```

I am sure your method is returning two values.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

It is simply a shorter way of assigning variables.

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

Is the same as:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

**More technical:**
As [TigerhawkT3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2617068/tigerhawkt3) says, they are not exactly the same.
For example in:

```
a = 0
b = 1

a, b = b, a
```

a is 1 and b is 0, Exchanging the values of a and b. This is different from

```
a = b
b = a
```

Where a and b are 1.

On the other hand, if we do:

```
x = [0, 1]
i = 0
i, x[i] = 1, 2
```

x is [0, 2]. First assign i, then x[i].

Comment: It is not technically the same. Try `a=0, b=1` and then `a,b = b,a` vs `a=b; b=a`.

Comment: I was reading JUST about it. Sorry, I wanted to help. These kinds of basic questions are not answered, right? Under what flag are they reported @TigerhawkT3?