# Declaring variables within parenthesis

Tags: python

I've come across this piece of code, and I was wondering what the parenthesis around the x and y variables declaration mean. Is it a declaration of a tuple?

```
 def in_bounds(self, id):
    (x, y) = id
    return 0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height
```

Comment: I did a thorough search for a similar question and didn't find one. If you could be so courteous as to include a link to the original question.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530125/what-does-a-comma-do-in-a-python-assignment) it is. It should be linked at the top of the page.

Comment: It's the same as `x, y  = id`.  The `()` are optional.  Both denote a tuple.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: Python does not have a concept of variable declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. That's sequence unpacking. The function expects `id` to be a sequence, typically a tuple or list, and assigns `x` and `y` to the corresponding values.

The line `(x, y) = id` is similar to the following:

```
x = id[0]
y = id[1]
```